# Android formatting text using TextWatcher

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to format my entered number in the format XXXXXX/XX/X I have come up with an algorithm but its pretty crap, instead I use index to insert a `/` at position 6 and 9, issue comes in on the deletion, if fails to delete as soon as it reaches any of the slashes, below is my code:

```
@Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            edt.removeTextChangedListener(this);


            if(TextUtils.isEmpty(s))
                return;

            String string  = s.toString().replace(" ", "");

            if(string.length() > 10)
                string = string.substring(0, 11);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(string);



            if(sb.length() >= 6)
                sb.replace(6, 7, "");

            if(sb.length() >= 6 )
                sb.insert(6, "/");


            if(sb.length() >= 9)
                sb.replace(9, 10, "");

            if(sb.length() >= 9)
                sb.insert(9, "/");


            edt.setText(sb.toString());
            edt.setSelection(sb.length());
            edt.addTextChangedListener(this);

        }
```

Anyone got a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

If this number formating is of a phone number try using https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber

Otherwise you could do:

```
x = x.substring(0, 6) + "/" + x.substring(6, 9) + "/" + x.substring(9, 11);
```